# Inequality and Euler's method

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, numerical-methods

> Let $y'(s)=y^2(s),y(0)=1$ be an ode on $s\in \mathbb{R}_+\setminus\{1\}$. Let $h_n=s_{n+1}-s_n$. Prove the following inequality with the Euler method $\forall n:s_n<1$ the following holds
>   $$y_n\leq \frac{1}{1-s_n}$$
>   The explicit Euler method is: $$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_nf(s_n,y_n)$$

The problem is, I don't know if I have to use somewhere Gronwall's lemma or if it is straight calculation. The solution to the ODE is $y(s)=\frac{1}{1-s}$ and here is what I've tried so far $$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_nf(s_n,y_n)$$
becomes
$$y_n=y_{n+1}-h_nf(s_n,y_n)$$
$$y_n=y_{n+1}-(s_{n+1}-s_n)y_n^2$$

But then I get stucked, since I don't see how I can remove the $y_{n+1}$ and $s_{n+1}$ terms without getting new recursive terms. Or do I have to use the geometric series?

Comment: First paragraph says "implicit Euler" all calculations you made seem to be for the "explicit Euler".

Comment: @el_tenedor Thanks you are right, I changed it. It just says Euler method but I strongly believe it should be the explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a proof by induction. You have, since $s_0=0$,
$$
y_0=1=\frac{1}{1-s_0}.
$$
If
$$
y_n\leq\frac{1}{1-s_n}
$$
then
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{n+1}&=y_n+h_n (y_n)^2\\
&\leq\frac{1}{1-s_n}+h_n\frac{1}{(1-s_n)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-(s_{n+1}-h_n)}+h_n\frac{1}{(1-(s_{n+1}-h_n))^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-s_{n+1}}-\frac{h_n^2}{(1-s_{n+1})(1-s_{n+1}+h_n)^2}\\
&\leq\frac{1}{1-s_{n+1}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
We are done.

Answer (score 0):

In recursions of the form $x_{n+1}=x_n+c_nx_n^2$ you can consider the reciprocal series $u_n=1/x_n$, $u_nx_n=1$, and use the geometric series/binomial identities to find helpful inequalities like
$$
u_{n+1}=\frac1{x_n(1+c_nx_n)}=u_n\frac{1-c_nx_n}{1-c_n^2x_n^2}>u_n-c_n
$$
Summation of this gives
$$
u_n>u_0-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_k
$$
so that in the original series
$$
x_n<\frac{x_0}{1-x_0\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_k}
$$